# What is "고답적" mean?

Tags: word-usage

When I'm surfing on the Internet, I saw the word "고답적".
What it means in English? I think it is very difficult word

Comment: did you check a dictionary? What is the context for this word? Where did you see it?

Answer (score 1):

"고답적" mean 세상에 초연(超然)하거나, 현실과 동떨어지게 사고하거나 행동하는 (것).

highbrow; high-toned; transcendent

https://korean.dict.naver.com/koendict/#/entry/koen/1033e49a588c46f0a574f007307409ed

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed an obscure one. This is my first time seeing that word.

These are my two cents to translate it:

- of an otherworldlically unrealistic mindset;
- thinking as if one is a spiritual being who doesn't belong to the world;
- unconcerned of earthly matter;
- differentiating oneself from earthly beings.